# (VB.NET) Why doesn't my login system work?

Tags: vb.net, authentication, passwords

OK. I have a code, and it should work, it DOES close the login form, but doesn't open the menu form.

```
            If username.Text = "lolman8776" Then
                If password.Text = "#########PASSWORD HIDDEN FROM THE INTERNET#########" Then
                    Form2.Show()
                    Me.Close()
                End If
                End If
```

What I don't understand, is that this code has no syntax errors and SHOULD WORK!
It shows form2 and THEN it closes itself, but Form2 never shows up.
I'm running VB.Net 2013 Community, as it was a free download. (I also registered it so it wasn't trial).
I have tried removing Me.Close() from Form1 and putting a line of code into Form2 that would close Form1:

```
    Form1.Close()
```

But, still nothing. I do not know why ANY METHOD won't work. I've searched high and low for an awnser, but to no success. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: If you have to write `#########PASSWORD HIDDEN FROM THE INTERNET#########`, you're definitely doing something wrong. Don't ever get in a habit of using plain passwords!

Comment: Are you instantiating your form? As in: `Dim myForm As New FormName()
myForm.Show()`

Comment: Most likely Form1 is the "Startup Object" in Project --> Properties?  When the startup form is closed, the entire application closes (which promptly closes Form2 with it).  Change `Me.Close()` to `Me.Hide()` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Well, I did make a new form, and set it to startup form to get it to appear FIRST. Because originally, I didn't make the login system first. I'll try Hide because it sounds like it can work.

Comment: No luck. Apparently HIDING the startup form will cause the whole app to close, too.

Comment: I tried not even hiding/closing form1, but just showing Form2 will cause the app to break. GREAT.

Comment: Bottom line, whatever form is the startup object controls the lifetime of the application.  When that instance is closed, the entire app is shutdown.  Make it clearer which forms are creating whom, and what the intended "flow" is, and we may be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment: "I tried not even hiding/closing form1, but just showing Form2 will cause the app to break."

I believe your issue lies around not instansiating your Form. The Show() method is not static and cannot be called directly on Form2. It must be called on an instance of your Form. For example:

`Dim myForm As New Form2()
myForm.Show()`

Please refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289529(v=vs.71).aspx) for a little more information.

Comment: `Form2.Show()` would display the **default instance** of Form2 and is perfectly legal, though confusing for some when they don't understand the difference between the default instance and a reference to an instance created with `new`.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233839.aspx) for more details: "A default instance is an instance of the class that is provided by the runtime and does not need to be declared and instantiated using the Dim and New statements."  So `Form2.Show()` is equivalent to `My.Forms.Form2.Show()`.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Very interesting! This feature doesn't appear to exist in C#.

Comment: That's correct, they are not available in C#.  Bit of history, the original classic VB6 had default instances, and they were **not included** in VB.Net 1.0 and 1.1 because Microsoft wanted to make VB.Net "on par" with C# in terms of correct OOP.  There was such an outcry from VB programmers making the transition to .Net, though, that they were brought back in VB.Net 2.0 and they've stayed ever since.